# How to get the length including punctuation mark (')?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to get the length including punctuation mark **`'`** ?
Example :-

```
SELECT LENGTH('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I') FROM dual
```

Comment: I don't understand your example. Can you give an example which includes the result you expect for a given input?

Comment: For above query, desired output is 27?

Comment: The question makes no sense at all.  `LENGTH()` only takes one argument, a string.  If the single quotes are embedded in the string, then they are counted.

Comment: Maybe he wants the length of all columns concatenated, for each record. Although assumptions are never good, a little more effort in asking the question should have been given so we don't have to guess.

Comment: @rcmuthu786 Still your comment is not helping very much.. Edit your post and show us what is your desired OUTPUT.

Comment: This question is very unclear. The OP has not  responded to requests for clarification by editing the question text to explain their requirements.  So, voting to close.

Comment: Hi all,

 i've used dbms_output.put_line (:Blk.item); for one item in form side.
length of the item is : 5(char)
while execution it returning value as 'M','U','T','U' with quotes(')

Then i have used with length dbms_output.put_line(length(:Blk.item)); then it's returning 14.

My question: is there any way to get the length with punctuation mark(')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT '''A'',''B'',''C'',''D'',''E'',''F'',''G'',''H'',''I''' FROM DUAL;
-- 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'

SELECT LENGTH('''A'',''B'',''C'',''D'',''E'',''F'',''G'',''H'',''I''') FROM DUAL;
-- 35
```

OR

```
DECLARE
    l_str VARCHAR2(100) := q'['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']';
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LENGTH(l_str));
END;
-- 35
```

Comment: Thanks @the_slk, this is the answer for my question.